# Get Eclipse to remember Package Explorer view

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

When I close Eclipse it remembers which files I had opened in the editor and re-opens them when I start it up again next.

Is there a way to also have it remember which packages/projects I had expanded in the Package Explorer? When I reopen Eclipse, it just goes back to everything being collapsed and showing me only the list of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package Explorer (and Project Explorer) don't support this. The older (and less functional) Navigator view does remember.

Comment: That's too bad... But I guess it's not a big deal. Thanks.